# Preventing Chrome from becoming maximized when dragging it up top?

Tags: google-chrome

Is it possible to prevent Chrome from becoming maximized when dragging it up top until it hits the highest part then it would automatically be maximized?

Example: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's in a place you might not expect. Here's where to look:

1. Click Start, type Ease, then click **Ease of Access Center**.
2. Scroll down a bit and click **Make the mouse easier to use**.
3. Scroll down to and enable the last checkbox in that window: **Prevent windows from being automatically arranged when moved to the edge of the screen**.
4. Click OK and you're done!

This will make all Windows (not just Chrome) to not maximize.

Comment: I assume you mean: "not maximize".

Comment: Corrected answer - cheers!